# Trying to figure out how to update values in subscribers attributes using php fuel sdk

Tags: php, fuel-sdk

I have it so I can update the subscribers email and subscription status,

```
function t_user_registration_messaging_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  require('FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9/ET_Client.php');
  $myclient = new ET_Client(true);
  $subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
  $subscriber->authStub = $myclient;
  $subscriber->props = array('SubscriberKey' => $user->mail);
  // This is where I tried to add the values in for the attributes I 
  // wanted updated, I tried several different things and cannot get 
  // it figured out.
  $sub_response = $subscriber->patch();
}
```

I am trying to find how to update specific attributes on a subscriber, but I can find zero documentation on it...
If anyone knows how to do this the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
function t_user_registration_messaging_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  require('FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9/ET_Client.php');
  $myclient = new ET_Client(true);
  $subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
  $subscriber->authStub = $myclient;
  $subscriber->props = array('SubscriberKey' => $user->mail);
```

This section here is the answer, I was getting confused on how to format it because of the StdClass Object, but was able to figure it out.

```
  $subscriber->props['Attributes'] = array(
    array('Name' => 'FNAME', 'Value' => 'Homer'),
    array('Name' => 'LNAME', 'Value' => 'Simpson'),
  );

  $sub_response = $subscriber->patch();
}
```

Comment: God forbid this be included in the god-awful documentation and 3+ year old SDK. Thank you for this, @Bryan!